# How does one convince anybody that the Messiah is not Hashem Tzidkenu יְהוָה צִדְקֵנוּ?

Tags: messiah, yirmiyahu--book-of

How does one convince anybody that the Messiah is not Hashem Tzidkenu יְהוָה צִדְקֵנוּ?

It seems there are several times our sages seem to be saying that the Messiah is Hashem Tzidkenu, but I refuse to believe that that is possible.

One example, and there are several, is

Eichah Rabbah 1, and one reads the following:

> מה שמו של מלך המשיח רבי אבא בר כהנא אמר ה' שמו, שנאמר (ירמיה כג, ו):
>   וזה שמו אשר יקראו ה' צדקנו   What is the name of the king Messiah? R'
>   Aba bar Kahana said: the Lord is his name, "... and this is his name
>   that he shall be called, The Lord is our righteousness." (Yirmiyahu
>   23:6)

ו  בְּיָמָיו תִּוָּשַׁע יְהוּדָה, וְיִשְׂרָאֵל יִשְׁכֹּן לָבֶטַח; וְזֶה-שְּׁמוֹ אֲשֶׁר-יִקְרְאוֹ, יְהוָה צִדְקֵנוּ

Comment: I don't understand the basis for your question -- your quote indicates the opinion is that the Messiah's name is "the Lord" but then you ask about "the Lord is our righteousness." Shouldn't you be asking about "the Lord"?

Comment: Please show a link to the quote that you cite.

Comment: the above quote is from https://www.sefaria.org/Eichah_Rabbah.1?lang=bi

Comment: @rosends the sage in question used both terms, מה שמו של מלך המשיח רבי אבא בר כהנא אמר ה' שמו, שנאמר (ירמיה כג, ו): וזה שמו אשר יקראו ה' צדקנו, https://www.sefaria.org/Eichah_Rabbah.1?lang=bi

Comment: @ninamag he used only one in his claim and cited a verse which included his phrase in a larger statement. One might wonder, if the verse said the larger phrase, why didn't he make a correlating claim? Why eliminate the second word?

Comment: @rosends are you saying the sage in question only used the term hashem? even then the messiah is not hashem. so why would our sage say, messiah is hashem?

Comment: @ninamag so then that should be the question because the sage didn't say that the name was hashem tzidkeinu.

Comment: and you can also ask about Tzemach and Menachem.

Comment: You cite only the opinion of R' Aba bar Kahana. Is his opinion the opinion of everyone? Do the other Sages agree with him? R' Hillel (Sanhedrin 99a) said that there wasn't going to be a Messiah anymore, but we don't agree with him.

Comment: ^ In addition to my comment above I'd like to make note that the R' Hillel I mentioned there is **not** [the Hillel you're thinking of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_the_Elder).

Comment: Why do you "refuse to believe that that is possible"?

Comment: @Alex it can not be that מה שמו של מלך המשיח רבי אבא בר כהנא אמר ה' שמו

Comment: I didn't ask what is impossible to believe. I asked why it is impossible to believe.

Comment: @Alex is it not part of using Hashem's Name in vain by calling another being Hashem?

Comment: @ninamag If that is the premise of your question you should edit it into the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74746/discussion-between-renato-grun-and-ninamag).

Answer (score 4):

The text does not say that the Moshiach will be Hashem Tzidkeinu, but that the (characteristic of) righteousness and (the holiness of) G-d’s name will be in Moshiach's name.

The midrash itself say that this refers to Hashem's name not to Hashem himself:

> דְּאָמַר רַבִּי לֵוִי טָבָא לִמְדִינְתָּא דִּשְׁמָהּ כְּשֵׁם
>   מַלְכָּהּ וְשֵׁם מַלְכָּהּ כְּשֵׁם אֱלֹהֶיהָ. טָבָא לִמְדִינְתָּא
>   דִּשְׁמָהּ כְּשֵׁם מַלְכָּהּ,...וְשֵׁם מַלְכָּהּ כְּשֵׁם אֱלֹהֶיהָ.

Just as the city of Jerusalem will be called Hashem Tzidkeinu (as stated elsewhere in [Jeremiah 33:16](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16030#v=16&showrashi=true):

> In those days, Judah shall be saved, and Jerusalem shall dwell
>   securely and this is the name that He shall call it, the *L-rd is our
>   righteousness.*

[Metzudat Dovid](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%9C%D7%92#%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7_%D7%98%D7%96_(%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7)(%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7)) says that this means Hashem will make us righteous when Jerusalem is reestablished.

We also can derive a lesson from that: Hashem will make us righteous when he (Moshiach) comes.

Comment: Your answer, therefore, is not based on the Pshat, but on a "derivation"? Also, for this answer that you gave, referencing, Jeremiah 33:16, what is stopping one from using the same reasoning in the answer by Yaacov Deane that "The following posuk in Navi [in this case, Yirmiyahu 33:16] has a Pasek after G-d’s name. And so the proper reading would be, 'and this is the name that G-d will call it, Tzidkeinu.'"

Comment: Why do you continue to assume that one should read "Hashem is he" and not "Hashem is his name"? Additionally, the continuation of the midrash (i added) answer your question very well.

Comment: I am looking for a plain meaning.

Comment: The plain meaning is explained in the continuation of the midrash. There it says that it refers Hashem's name, not to Hashem himself.

Comment: @Renato_Grun we are commanded not to carry or take Hashem's name in vain, why then call somebody HASHEM (i.e. YHWH), unless the person is indeed YHWH, which of course, in this case, it is against our mindset.

Comment: "why then call somebody HASHEM...." -- the reason is quoted in the answer I already posted. "unless the person is indeed YHWH...." ---
 Then, giving the name "Tzemach" (a branch) to Moshiach he is required  to be a branch??

Answer (score 1):

The Navi (Yirmiyahu) and the Eicha Rabbati you quote are understood by looking at the posuk which precedes, namely, Yirmiyahu 23:5.

> הִנֵּ֨ה יָמִ֤ים בָּאִים֙ נְאֻם־יְהוָ֔ה וַהֲקִמֹתִ֥י לְדָוִ֖ד צֶ֣מַח צַדִּ֑יק וּמָ֤לַךְ מֶ֙לֶךְ֙ וְהִשְׂכִּ֔יל וְעָשָׂ֛ה מִשְׁפָּ֥ט וּצְדָקָ֖ה בָּאָֽרֶץ׃

The reference is to the *righteous* one which G-d will make *sprout* from King David’s line. (צֶ֣מַח צַדִּ֑יק) “I will raise up for David a righteous sprout”

The following posuk in Navi (Yirmiyahu 23:6) has a *Pasek* after G-d’s name. And so the proper reading would be, “and this is the name that G-d will call him, Tzidkeinu.” (Our Righteous one)

The emphasis of Rabbi Abba Bar Kahana in your quoted Midrash is that G-d calls him this name.

Comment: As pointed out by @rosends, This does not answer the plain reading of the Eicha Rabba, which is מה שמו של מלך המשיח רבי אבא בר כהנא אמר ה' שמו

Comment: @ninamag The language in the Midrash is abbreviated. It lists the response of Rabbi Abba Bar Kahana to the question of what is King Moshiach’s name? G-d says his name, like is found in Yirmiyahu 23:6. Anyone reading otherwise would be ignoring the plain meaning of the text in the Yirmiyahu cited.

Comment: @YaacovDeane You wrote in your last sentence, "The emphasis of Rabbi Abba Bar Kahana in your quoted Midrash is that G-d calls him this name." But the quoted Midrash says Rabbi Abba Bar Kahana referred to the Mashiach's Name as YHWH: מה שמו של מלך המשיח רבי אבא בר כהנא אמר ה' שמו

Comment: This is nice, but is not the plain meaning. In the plain meaning a Psik after a Merkha is not a stronger break than a Tipcha. The reading you describe would be marked  וְזֶה־שְּׁמ֧וֹ אֲ‍ֽשֶׁר־יִקְרְא֛וֹ יְהוָ֖ה ׀ צִדְקֵֽנוּ. The Psik here is in all likelihood to ensure God's name isn't mispronounced by being slurred into the next word.

Comment: Would you also read Ex 17:15 as God giving the name?

Comment: @magicker72 quote here in full "Ex 17:15" and make your point, please.

Comment: @ninamag The text is [here](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0217.htm).  The second half of the verse is the same construction as in Jer 23:6 (and 33:16).

Comment: @DoubleAA I hear you. But I’m also looking at the usage of Psik like in Tehillim 85:9 which is clearly intended to separate the two names of G-d, like is found here in Yirmiyahu regarding G-d’s name and that of Melech HaMoshiach. And this follows the explanation of the function of Psik at the end of chapter 2 in Sefer Mishpatei HaTa’amim. And yes, I am aware Tehillim can be different.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Tehillim 85:9 is like Yeshaya 42:5 and Yehoshua 22:22. Indeed Psikim show up around God's names. Here though there is only one name of God. Something else is going on, as magicker indicated.

Comment: @DoubleAA You may find this more detailed discussion of the multiple uses of Psik of interest.  http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7218&st=&pgnum=62

Comment: @DoubleAA If you look at the discussion of function 2 for the Psik, it is what applies to the two usages you cite. They are relevant as a separation in terms of the different names of G-d which apply to different functions according to kabbalah. But the Psik I am discussing with Yirmiyahu 23:6 is like function 3 of Psik as described in Mishpatei HaTa'amim.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm waiting for your follow-up response to these. I think you have a point that I could learn from.